# Reading debug information from DOS MZ executable

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, debug-symbols, tasm

I am trying to write an 8086 emulator + debugger. There is a lot information about writing first one, but nothing about second one. I need to read debug information that TASM includes in an MZ executable with commands `tasm.exe /zi main.asm` and `tlink.exe /v main.obj` (to show program listing). That information appends directly after opcodes in `.exe` file. Turbo debugger successfully reads this data and shows it. But how does it do that? How to implement such functionality?

Comment: This is most likely compiler specific. So the debug information format will depend on the compiler. Maybe the format is documented somewhere, but I doubt it. I suggest to run TD in your emulator first ;-)

Comment: If the format is `COFF` you can maybe find some information in the specificaion on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source of information about Borland's TLINK/Turbo Debugger debugging information is probably the *Borland Open Architecture Handbook* (available in many places, e.g. [here](http://cs.uns.edu.ar/~jechaiz/organizacion/TechDocs/boa.txt)). It describes the updated, 32-bit supporting debug info (see "Symbol table format" section), but a lot of it still applies to 16-bit one.

Ralph Brown also has a short description of the header: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/it/24/16.html